# Adding rows above output

Tags: powershell

I am creating a custom object as below:

```
$props = @{
  Name   = "John"
  Gender = "Male"
  Age    = 30
}

$c = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
```

For the above code the output will be as:

```
Name Gender Age
---- ------ ---
John Male    30
```

How do I add more rows above the output by altering the code?

Comment: Define "add more rows" by adding an example of desired output.

Comment: i suppose if you need more rows you need an array or objects

Comment: $props.Add("tralala", "trilili") ?

Answer (score 3):

```
PS> $people=@()
PS> $people += [PsCustomObject]@{
  Name   = "John"
  Gender = "Male"
  Age    = 30
}
PS> $people += [PsCustomObject]@{
  Name   = "Jane"
  Gender = "Female"
  Age    = 20
}
PS> $people
Name Gender Age
---- ------ ---
John Male    30
Jane Female  20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array and then add multiple objects to the array:

```
#define as array
$people = @()

#build object with the data you want added
$person = New-Object System.Object
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue "John"
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Gender -NotePropertyValue "Male"
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Age -NotePropertyValue 30

#add object to array            
$people += $person
```

`$people` will then contain only details for John:

```
> $people

Name Gender Age
---- ------ ---
John Male    30
```

You can then add another person in the same way:

```
$person = New-Object System.Object
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue "Jane"
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Gender -NotePropertyValue "Female"
$person | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Age -NotePropertyValue 21

$people += $person
```

This will add another person object to the people array:

```
> $people

Name Gender Age
---- ------ ---
John Male    30
Jane Female  21
```

---

You can then retrieve each item:

```
> $people[1]

Name Gender Age
---- ------ ---
Jane Female  21
```

Or a specific items property by name:

```
> $people[1].Name

Jane
```

And use a foreach loop to get properties from all items and

```
> foreach ($person in $people) {
    Write-Output "$($person.Name) is a $($person.Age) old $($person.Gender)."
}

John is a 30 old Male.
Jane is a 21 old Female.
```